# How do we dispute a declined flag?

Tags: feature-request, flagging, specific-flag

I flagged [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445760/good-example-showing-why-limits-must-exist-in-limit-product-rule) post as *primarily opinion based*. It was declined. I think this decision is incorrect and would like it adjudicated if that is possible. If there is no facility to dispute declined flags, we should consider adding it.

My reasoning is as follows. The OP wants an example of how to show that $0 \times \infty$ product limits are wrong without having to point out that the $\infty$ part is self-evidently wrong. He does not believe this to be the case because, quote: "students just think that because 0 times anything is 0 the answer is 0. And they happen to be right". Which is of course total nonsense, and this is exactly the sort of mistake that should be *taught by the OP*. His dispute **is** primarily opinion based, given that it has no logical basis, and so I believe my flag is appropriate. If you read the thread so far, he seems impervious to any reasoning counter to his belief.

If you agree that this flag should have been declined, I would very much like to know why you think the OP's reasoning is appropriate, because I do not. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It seems that having a flags declined cause no consequences. Why it worth making extra resources to add a system to depute that?

Comment: @JohnMa: I don't understand your comment. I'm not worried about the impact on *me*, but I am worried about bad questions being treated as reasonable. Bad questions should be deleted. Whoever downvoted I would appreciate a reason.

Comment: The only new feather that is suggested in the question is that "if there is no facility to dispute declined flags, we should consider adding it". I do not agree to that, hence the downvote (this downvote has nothing to do with the "quality" of your post. Downvotes here on meta are used differently). Whether or not that is a bad question is not judged only by you, but the whole community. Everyone (with sufficient rep) can vote to close questions. The question will be closed if five people voted to closed.

Comment: @JohnMa: I disagree. Math is not subjective at some level. The whole community can still be wrong about the quality of a post, which is precisely why I am asking for adjudication. I realize that in social media votes dictate,but I am claiming this is inappropriate at some level for math. I am asking for adjudication precisely because the community voting process is *failing*. This is comparable to appealing a court decision, which asks for expert (judges) opinion to intervene. It is not wrong to have a system that says the community votes might be incorrect on occasion.

Comment: Even if Math is not subjective, whether or not a question is bad or opinion-based is quite subjective. If you think the OP of the question has serious misunderstanding in math, point that out by writing an answer or leaving a comment, that helps the OP and finishes the question. IMO, in voting/flaging posts, you should concentrate on the presentation of the question. No one will be here to do that "ultimate math judge" that you are hoping for.

Comment: @JohnMa:" No one will be here to do that "ultimate math judge" that you are hoping for"  Um, why not? What are the moderators for if they are not willing to be "ultimate math judges"? If they are not willing to be this, then we have a real problem in my view.  You are just wrong that questions cannot be opinion based. They most certainly can be! And we need moderators to make that determination when the community will not. I get that this is not democratic, but if the community is not up to the task, we need to pass to the "experts" who *are* up to the task.

Comment: Probably the moderator will answer your first question. I am not saying that a question cannot be opinion-based, I am saying that whether or not it is opinion-based is subjective.

Comment: @JohnMa: Abstractly, I agree, but my point about math theses being objective at some point still applies. At some point they are *not* subjective, and it is reasonable for a moderator to weigh in.

Comment: For those interested, the review transcript is http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/485961

Comment: The moderators are absolutely, positively, not "ultimate math judges". That's not part of their job description, that's not what they campaign on when they're up for election, that's not what voters have in mind (or, it's only a small part of what voters have in mind) when they elect them.

Comment: Oh dear, there is one question that some think should be closed, but isn't. This is terrible.

Answer (score 9):

Flag decisions are not reversable. Once a flag has been been marked helpful/disputed/declined, it's a done deal. An [old feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105542) to allow moderators to reverse flag decisions has been marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). I don't think there is any reason to expect a change in SE's stance on this, especially as the effects of having **many** declined flags is only, at worst, a temporary ban on flagging (and not the hell-ban it used to be).

Note, in particular, your "primarily opinion-based" close-flag caused the question to enter the close votes review queue. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/485961) is the result of that review. The *review process* is what caused your flag to be declined (the one close vote was done for another reason than POB). (It is entirely likely that no moderator came across your flag while it was still pending.)

(If you feel the question should be closed, you could also add a message to the [Reopen? Undelete? Close? Delete?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2165/reopen-undelete-close-delete) chat room. Though I expect most of the users who patrol that room will also see this meta-question. When you gain enough reputation you will be able to cast a close vote yourself.)

Comment: "At worst, a temporary ban on flagging". Aren't flag stats used as a campaign tool during moderators elections?  Not that I ever considered being a moderator, but every time I felt one of my flags was unjustly declined, this is exactly what came to my mind.

Comment: @GitGud Flag stats are mentioned, but I don't think anyone would seriously think that having some declined flags makes someone unqualified to be a moderator. Moreover, I personally doubt that flag stats are even considered by most voters. There's another, far more prominent number that correlates to electedness _much_ better. (I would also consider being temporarily flag banned to be a worse outcome than not being elected moderator, so I stand by my "at worst....")